# C#: Why is this variable in scope and out of scope at the same time?

Tags: c#, scope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Variable Scoping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049330/c-variable-scoping)

I've run into something I've never encountered before. *I'm not looking for a fix* as I know how to solve it. What I'd like to know is what the compiler is doing. This is just example code:

```
if (true)
{
    int x = 0;
}
int x = 0;
```

That code produces the error "A local variable 'x' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'x'".

However, it I change the code to this:

```
if (true)
{
    int x = 0;
}
x = 0;
```

I get the error "Cannot resolve symbol 'x'".

So, what's going on here? How is it that x is both in scope and out of scope?

Comment: I've noticed this before and wondered about it. Personally I'm surprised the first doesn't compile, while it seems right that the second one should not compile.

Answer (score 5):

A variable's scope is the entire block in which it is declared. However, you can't *refer* to it until *after* the declaration.

Eric Lippert has a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/03/what-s-the-difference-part-two-scope-vs-declaration-space-vs-lifetime.aspx) on this which goes into more detail. EDIT: And as Eric points out, [another one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/02/simple-names-are-not-so-simple.aspx)...

Comment: You could just point them to a related answer from him :o)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049330/c-variable-scoping/2050864#2050864

Comment: @Matthew: I knew there was a blog post; I didn't know Eric had answered an SO question.

Comment: Neither did I at first but I knew I saw the question before.

Comment: Thanks Jon; actually this article is more germane to the specific question: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/02/simple-names-are-not-so-simple.aspx

Answer (score 0):

**Its not**, simply because C# allows you to declare/define variables anywhere in the program its scope is the entire block in which it is declared ans so it is making the `x` predeclared/(in scope)  for `x` in `if` block