# C# local variable scope

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [confused with the scope in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196941/confused-with-the-scope-in-c-sharp)

It appears that in C# a variable defined with the local scope to if/else/loop block is conflicting with variable defined outside following that block - see code snipped. An equivalent code compiles fine under C/C++ and Java. Is this expected behavior in C#?

```
public void f(){
  if (true) {
    /* local if scope */
    int a = 1;
    System.Console.WriteLine(a);
  } else {
    /* does not conflict with local from the same if/else */
    int a = 2;
    System.Console.WriteLine(a);
  }

  if (true) {
    /* does not conflict with local from the different if */
    int a = 3;
    System.Console.WriteLine(a);
  }

  /* doing this:
   * int a = 5;
   * results in: Error 1 A local variable named 'a' cannot be declared in this scope
   *  because it would give a different meaning to 'a', which is already used in a 
   *  'child' scope to denote something else
   * Which suggests (IMHO incorrectly) that variable 'a' is visible in this scope
   */

  /* doing this: 
   * System.Console.WriteLine(a);
   * results in: Error 1 The name 'a' does not exist in the current context..
   * Which correctly indicates that variable 'a' is not visible in this scope
   */
}
```

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/02/simple-names-are-not-so-simple.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [confused with the scope in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196941/confused-with-the-scope-in-c-sharp) and [C# Variable Scoping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049330/c-sharp-variable-scoping).

Comment: Thank you Servy. Per blog:  3) Local variables are in scope throughout the entire block in which the declaration occurs. **This is in contrast with C++, in which local variables are in scope in their block only at points after the declaration**

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is how C# works.

When declaring a scope, any local variable from an outer scope is also known - there is no way to qualify that a local variable within the scope should override the local variable from outside.

Comment: It appears it boils down to "in-scope" definition. In C# unlike in (C++), if local variable is defined inside the block - it is in-scope within entire block regardless of the place of declaration. Whereas, in C++, local variable defined inside the block is in-scope **only at point after the declaration**

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are concerned with the order of declaration (redeclaring `a` *after* the `if` blocks).

Consider the case that it is declared *before* the `if` blocks. Then you would expect it to be available within the scope of those blocks.

```
int a = 1;

if(true)
{
  var b = a + 1; // accessing a from outer scope
  int a = 2; // conflicts
}
```

There is not really a concept of "not in scope *yet*" at compile time.

You can actually create an inner scope with just bare curly braces:

```
{
   int a = 1;
}

if(true)
{
   int a = 2; // works because the a above is not accessible in this scope
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That's normal behavior.

Sam Ng wrote a nice blog-post about this a while ago: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/samng/archive/2007/11/09/local-variable-scoping-in-c.aspx

Answer (score 3):

There are already some good answers but I gave a look to the C# 4 language specs to clarify this.

We can read in §1.24 about scopes:

> Scopes can be nested, and an inner scope may redeclare the meaning of a
> name from an outer scope (this does not, however, remove the
> restriction imposed by §1.20 that within a nested block it is not
> possible to declare a local variable with the same name as a local
> variable in an enclosing block).

And this is the cited part in §1.20:

> A declaration defines a name in the declaration space to which the
> declaration belongs. Except for overloaded members (§1.23), it is a
> compile-time error to have two or more declarations that introduce
> members with the same name in a declaration space. It is never
> possible for a declaration space to contain different kinds of members
> with the same name
>
> [...]
>
> Note that blocks that occur as or within the body of a function member
> or anonymous function are nested within the local variable declaration
> space declared by those functions for their parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is expected because you are defining the variable within the local statement. If you were to define your variable at the class level, you would have different results.