# Check if string is null

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, byte

I want to check if my variable(**crphoto1**) is null. If **crphoto1** is null, crPhoto1Data should be null and when crphoto1 is not null crPhoto1Data should be like this **byte[] crPhoto1Data = File.ReadAllBytes(crphoto1);**. The code belows gives me error how can I fix it?

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(crphoto1))
{
    string crPhoto1Data = "";
}
else
{
    byte[] crPhoto1Data = File.ReadAllBytes(crphoto1);
}


var ph1link = "http://" + ipaddress + Constants.requestUrl + "Host=" + host + "&Database=" + database + "&Contact=" + contact + "&Request=tWyd43";
string ph1contentType = "application/json";
JObject ph1json = new JObject
{
    { "ContactID", crcontactID },
    { "Photo1", crPhoto1Data }
};
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: @RufusL in { "Photo1", crPhoto1Data } the error is "The name 'crPhoto1Data' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: You should update your question with the error message rather than in the comments. The error means that you have to declare the variable outside of the `if` block because variables are scoped to the block in which they're declared. And you can't set it to more than one type.

Comment: how can I fix this?

Comment: The scope of  both versions of `crPhoto1Data` (same name with different types) is wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# local variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060748/c-sharp-local-variable-scope)

Comment: @John3136 how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to use a variable that is declared inside a block with a narrower scope (you define `crPhoto1Data` inside the `if` block). Another problem is that you're trying to set it to more than one type.

One way solve this is to create the `JObject` in an `if/else` statement (or using the ternary operator as in my sample below):

```
JObject ph1json = string.IsNullOrEmpty(crphoto1)
    ? new JObject
    {
        {"ContactID", crcontactID},
        {"Photo1", ""}
    }
    : new JObject
    {
        {"ContactID", crcontactID},
        {"Photo1", File.ReadAllBytes(crphoto1)}
    };
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be shorter and easier to just have one `new JObject` and set `{"Photo1", string.IsNullOrEmpty(crphoto1) ? "" : File.ReadAllBytes(crphoto1)}`?

Comment: I assume it's just for clarity, Since OP doesn't really seem to take real note as shown in the comments of his first post.