# Why is a private variable defined in for conflict with the same variable outside?

Tags: c#

In my mental model, counter variables defined inside `for` become private because it cannot be access from outside as follows.

```
    for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++) ;
    //Console.WriteLine(x); x does not exist in the current context
```

My confusion occurs when I declared the same variable as follows,

```
    for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++) ;
    //Console.WriteLine(x); x does not exist in the current context, but why cannot I declare
    //int x = 1;
```

Why does the compiler disallow me to declare a variable with the same name as another inaccessible variable? It does not make sense to me. :-)

To make more confusing compare it with

```
    {
        int x = 1;
    }
    {
        int x = 2;
    }
```

which is allowed by the compiler. But both below are not allowed.

```
static void Foo()
{
    int x = 1;
    { int x = 2; }
}

static void Bar()
{
    { int x = 2; }
    int x = 3;
}
```

Comment: This is explained in [C# Variable Scoping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049330/c-sharp-variable-scoping).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour is covered in section 3.7 of the [language spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx). It says, “The scope of a local variable declared in a [local-variable-declaration (8.5.1)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664742%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is the block in the which the declaration occurs”.

The scope of `x` is therefore the entire function, and that means that the use in the for loop is a re=use, and therefore is not allowed.

***This behavior is inteded to make incorrect re-use of variable names (such as in a cut and paste) less likely.***

Answer (score 1):

aleroot already gave the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22127588/447156) to your first part. I want to answer second part of your question.

```
{
     int x = 1;
}
{
     int x = 2;
}
```

which is allowed by the compiler.

Yes, because there is no local variable `x` in the same scope or any nested scope. For example;

```
static void Main()
{
    int x;
    {
        int y;
        int x; // Error - x already defined in same scope or parrent scope.
    }
    {
        int y; // OK - there is no y in the same scope or any nested scope.
    }
    Console.Write (y); // Error - there is no y in same scope of any parrent scope.
}
```

Comment: If the first `int x;` is moved to the last row, for example after `Console.WriteLine(y);` the compiler is still unhappy. In my mental model, it should not be a problem because it comes last.

Comment: @TheLastError It is because there is an already defined `x` in child scope. You can't declare _local-variable-declaration_ in current or parrent scope if there is an already in child scope (doesn't matter comes last or first).

Comment: OK. Thanks. It is counter intuitive at a glance. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Couse for loop almost declared x varible inside it, so u cant redeclared x varible, as can exists only one declaration in scope.