# Why does declaring a variable of the same name as in for loop causes variable name ambiguity in C# in opposition to Java

Tags: java, c#, scope

As for Java refugee this code is perfectly fine. The `int i` lives in the loop only and the second `int i` causes no conflict. So there should be no problem. Altough, This code in C# causes `i` variable ambiguity.

```
static void Main(String[] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
    }
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 10) { i++; }
}
```

Thus(beign naive) this code should be valid

```
static void Main(String[] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
    }
    i++;
}
```

but it says the `i` variable is not declared which as expected is true.
Finally only  nesting second `int i` in the block fixes the ambiguity:

```
static void Main(String[] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
    }
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 10) { i++; }
    }
}
```

The question is: what rule/mechanism of C# language causes variable name ambiguity in the first example given?

The printscreen from VS2013:

[image]

Comment: Side-note: Eric Lippert has an interesting series of blog posts regarding that error message and its friends, [here](http://ericlippert.com/2014/09/25/confusing-errors-for-a-confusing-feature-part-one/).

Comment: Duplicate contains answer by Eric Lippert who goes into all details (and cover `for` blocks) - http://stackoverflow.com/a/2050864/477420.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: ??? :-)