# Variable in child scope preventing definition of variable in parent

Tags: c#, language-design

Today I discovered a, presumably, "feature" of [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23):

> error CS0136: A local variable named `foo` cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to `foo`, which is already used in a `child` scope to denote something else

Which can simply be reproduced by trying to compile this snippet:

```
if (false) {
    int foo = 42;
}
int foo = 1337;
```

Why can't I define `foo` in the parent scope? The `foo` from the child scope is not visible in the parent scope, nor would it be still allocated, it's therefore absolutely legal in any proper language. What did I miss? What is the reasoning behind this?

Comment: It's obviously rather a design choice than a feature: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2049377/2695832

Comment: Sweet! Thanks a lot. For some reason I couldn't find anything related to that. Yes, it's a duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049330/c-sharp-variable-scoping http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156449/why-cant-a-duplicate-variable-name-be-declared-in-a-nested-local-scope http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649947/why-doesnt-c-sharp-allow-me-to-use-the-same-variable-name-in-different-scopes

Comment: @OnkelToob I really feel like C# was designed for a toddler ...