# How to create a new variable in a function with the same name of a parameter passed to that function in C#?

Tags: c#

It's easier if I just state that in this:

```
public static void GetObstacles(params string[] ObstacleLayers)
{
    foreach (string Layer in ObstacleLayers)
    {
        var Layer = _tiledMap.GetLayer<TiledMapTileLayer>(Layer);
    }
}
```

I want the created variable `var Layer` to be named after the `string Layer`.

Comment: why do you care for names of variables? Just name the string-variable `layerName`, and the `TiledMapTileLayer`-variable `layer`.

Comment: You cannot -- this is forbidden by the language

Comment: You just have to be a bit more careful when naming variables, perhaps `foreach (string Layer in ObstacleLayers)` could have been `foreach (string obstacleLayer in ObstacleLayers)`

Comment: _"I want the created variable var Layer to be named after the string Layer"_ Think about what happens when you do something like `Console.WriteLine(Layer.GetType().Name);`, for example.

Comment: Are you looking for a `Dictionary<string,something>`? You don't create new *variables* whilst your code is running.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649947/why-doesnt-c-sharp-allow-me-to-use-the-same-variable-name-in-different-scopes

Comment: "_It is an error for the local variable declaration space of a block and a nested local variable declaration space to contain elements with the same name. Thus, within a nested declaration space it is not possible to declare a local variable or constant with the same name as a local variable or constant in an enclosing declaration space_" from C# Language Specification, secssion 3.3, page 57.

Comment: Easily set: give **different** things a **different** name. Your string surely is something different then the tilelayer, isn´t it? A name of a variable should always determine its purpose. How would you differentiate between a layer and a layer, if using the same name for different things was possible?

Answer (score 0):

The thing you ask for is as if you were asking for designate a cat as a dog the same time like in a schrodinger box.

However, you have the notion of [dynamic](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/reference-types#the-dynamic-type) but this does not apply to [foreach](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/C-Sharp-foreach-loop) because you can't assign the iteratored var and here the goal is not to modulate it.

Therefore you need to write:

```
foreach (string layerName in ObstacleLayers)
{
  var layer = _tiledMap.GetLayer<TiledMapTileLayer>(layerName);
  // do something with the layer
}
```

So the string element you iterate over from the collection is used to get an object instance of type `Layer` (perhaps) to work on.

It seems that you did not understand or learned what are [loops](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_loops.htm) and [variables](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_variables.htm) and their [usage](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-variable) as well as [scope](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c-sharp/).